# How to log into my new spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring boot and while I can run my project, when I try to access it, hoping for a blank page, I get a login/password prompt and, though I've defined a few values on my application.properties file, I always get an error.

`pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>b.c.g</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>appName</name>
    <description>appDescription</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mobile</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`application.properties` is:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app
spring.datasource.name=app
spring.datasource.username=app
spring.datasource.password=appPassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

security.user.name=master
security.user.password=abc123
```

And, finally, my main class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Controller
public class AppNameApplication {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String entry() {
        return "AppName";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppNameApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Though I'm a seasoned Spring user, I'm learning Spring boot to add to my development skills.

The error I get on the browser is:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback. Tue Aug 09 13:33:59 BRT 2016 There was an
>   unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401). Bad credentials

I know there's nothing much going on now, but is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't I be, at least, able to login?

Comment: What do you mean log in? What part of your app manages users and/or authenticates them?

Comment: You are using the spring security starter, so I think you could try removing that first to check if you can access to your endpoint. If that works, then you need to learn how to config spring security. Btw, if you want to learn SpringBoot start step by step instead of adding everything in one shoot.

Comment: See here for Spring boot security config: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post this answer as a more detailed "comment", since I can't comment with nice details.

In your pom.xml you have added the Spring Security starter:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This means that Spring will enable security to access your endpoint, hence your *unauthorized* error. **Spring Security's default behavior is to lock down your entire application**.

So, you have to configure spring security accordingly to enable your access.

As detailed in this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

You have to create a WebSecurity configurer, below the example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Before getting involved with Spring Security, you could first remove the security starter and try accessing your endpoints. Once you confirm that your API works as expected, then you can start playing with Security. Likewise, I'd suggest you to start from scratch with no starters and adding them one by one meanwhile you learn instead of adding everything in one shoot.

Comment: Is the default `spring-boot-starter-security` behavior to block everything?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I cannot say 'yes' because I'd be lying but I remember I faced the same problem and fixed it when added the web configurer with `permitAll`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, confirmed, found [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-spring-boot-app-with-user-authentication#set-up-your-spring-boot-project) that Spring Security's default is to lock down your entire application.

Comment: @gtludwig, confirmed. Spring security locks the whole app unless you configure it.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, yes, buddy! Thanks!